# Getting Parse error for elasticsearch-py

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I am trying to search my entire elasticsearch data for a certain word "tsbu" within a time range. When I try running this, I get a SearchParseException and Parse Failure.

```
es = Elasticsearch()

doc = {
        "query": {
            "match" : { 
                "message" : "tsbu"
            }
        }, 
        "range" : { 
            "@timestamp" : { 
                "gte" : "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z", 
                "lte" : "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"
            }
        }
    }

print es.search(index="_all", body=doc)
```

The complete error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "essearch.py", line 22, in <module>
print es.search(index="_all", body=doc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 504, in search
params=params, body=body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 307, in perform_request
status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 89, in perform_request
self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 105, in _raise_error
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[mPhuId4qSpa5osrqfeG5Tw][.kibana][0]: SearchParseException[[.kibana][0]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"match": {"message": "tsbu"}}, "range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z", "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[.kibana][0]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [range]]]; }{[mPhuId4qSpa5osrqfeG5Tw][logstash-2015.06.08][0]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.08][0]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"match": {"message": "tsbu"}}, "range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z", "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.08][0]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [range]]]; }{[mPhuId4qSpa5osrqfeG5Tw][logstash-2015.06.09][0]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.09][0]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"match": {"message": "tsbu"}}, "range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z", "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.09][0]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [range]]]; }{[mPhuId4qSpa5osrqfeG5Tw][logstash-2015.06.10][0]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.10][0]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"match": {"message": "tsbu"}}, "range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z", "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.10][0]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [range]]]; }{[mPhuId4qSpa5osrqfeG5Tw][logstash-2015.06.08][1]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.08][1]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"match": {"message": "tsbu"}}, "range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z", "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.08][1]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [range]]]; }{[mPhuId4qSpa5osrqfeG5Tw][logstash-2015.06.09][1]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.09][1]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"match": {"message": "tsbu"}}, "range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z", "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.09][1]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [range]]]; }{[mPhuId4qSpa5osrqfeG5Tw][logstash-2015.06.10][1]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.10][1]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"match": {"message": "tsbu"}}, "range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z", "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.10][1]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [range]]]; }{[mPhuId4qSpa5osrqfeG5Tw][logstash-2015.06.08][2]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.08][2]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"match": {"message": "tsbu"}}, "range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z", "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.08][2]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [range]]]; }{[mPhuId4qSpa5osrqfeG5Tw][logstash-2015.06.09][2]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.09][2]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"match": {"message": "tsbu"}}, "range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z", "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.09][2]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [range]]]; }{[mPhuId4qSpa5osrqfeG5Tw][logstash-2015.06.10][2]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.10][2]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"match": {"message": "tsbu"}}, "range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z", "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.10][2]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [range]]]; }{[mPhuId4qSpa5osrqfeG5Tw][logstash-2015.06.08][3]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.08][3]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"match": {"message": "tsbu"}}, "range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z", "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.08][3]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [range]]]; }{[mPhuId4qSpa5osrqfeG5Tw][logstash-2015.06.09][3]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.09][3]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"match": {"message": "tsbu"}}, "range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z", "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.09][3]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [range]]]; }{[mPhuId4qSpa5osrqfeG5Tw][logstash-2015.06.10][3]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.10][3]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"match": {"message": "tsbu"}}, "range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z", "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.10][3]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [range]]]; }{[mPhuId4qSpa5osrqfeG5Tw][logstash-2015.06.08][4]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.08][4]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"match": {"message": "tsbu"}}, "range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z", "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.08][4]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [range]]]; }{[mPhuId4qSpa5osrqfeG5Tw][logstash-2015.06.09][4]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.09][4]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"match": {"message": "tsbu"}}, "range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z", "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.09][4]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [range]]]; }{[mPhuId4qSpa5osrqfeG5Tw][logstash-2015.06.10][4]: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.10][4]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"match": {"message": "tsbu"}}, "range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z", "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"}}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[logstash-2015.06.10][4]: query[message:tsbu],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [range]]]; }]')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is almost correct. The error your get states `...Parse Failure [Failed to parse source...`, which basically means that your query is ill-formed and doesn't comply to the [Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-queries.html).

The `range` query needs to be combined with the `match` query (using a `bool/must` query) and both need to be nested inside the `query`, like this

```
doc = {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "tsbu"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The end result is that you need `tsbu` to match the `message` field **AND** the `@timestamp` to be within the specified date range.

**UPDATE**

In order to have either `message` match `tsbu` or `host` match `vcs` but still require the `timestamp` to match, you can do it like this:

```
doc = {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "message": "tsbu"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "host": "vcs"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "2015-06-09T14:44:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2015-06-09T14:50:00.000Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to either have the message field to have tsbu or another field host to have vcs, but still require the timestamp. How would that be done? Sorry about the noob question, I am very new to Query DSL.